# Finding input data - Run time error 13 - Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build a macro, which should find input data in an excel row. Everything works fine when the input data is somewhere available in the excel rows. But when the the input data is not available in the rows, I get a run time error 13 - Type mismatch. I don't understand why this is happening.

My input data, which I declare as a Variant, is something like:

- 040234-A
- 0463796
- 8745-00

These will be found, but if I change the input data to for example 040234- or 04637 I'll get the error.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this? In the following you'll find my code. Here "Gescanntes Material" is the important input data. I get the error message at:

MaterialDatenbankZeile = Application.Match(GescanntesMaterial, Range(MaterialienRange), 0)

Thanks!

```
Sub Traceability()

Worksheets("Materialien").Activate

Dim GescanntesEndgeraet As Variant
Dim GescanntesMaterial As Variant
Dim ZeileEndgeraetStart As Integer
Dim ZeileEndgeraetEnd As Integer
Dim MaterialDatenbankZeile As Integer
Dim MaterialDatenbank As Variant


GescanntesEndgeraet = Worksheets("Uebersicht").Cells(7, "C").Value

GescanntesMaterial = Worksheets("Uebersicht").Cells(11, "C").Value


ZeileEndgeraetStart = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(GescanntesEndgeraet, Range("A:A"), 0)

ZeileEndgeraetEnd = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(GescanntesEndgeraet, Range("A:A"), 0) + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), GescanntesEndgeraet) - 1


Dim MaterialienRange As String

Let MaterialienRange = "B" & ZeileEndgeraetStart & ":" & "B" & ZeileEndgeraetEnd

MaterialDatenbankZeile = Application.Match(GescanntesMaterial, Range(MaterialienRange), 0) 

    If IsError(MaterialDatenbankZeile) Then

        Let MaterialDatenbank = "A"
    
    Else
        
        MaterialDatenbankZeile = MaterialDatenbankZeile + ZeileEndgeraetStart - 1

        MaterialDatenbank = Worksheets("Materialien").Cells(MaterialDatenbankZeile, "B").Value

    End If
    
    If MaterialDatenbank = GescanntesMaterial Then

        Worksheets("Uebersicht").Cells(7, "F").Value = "true"
    
    Else
    
        Worksheets("Uebersicht").Cells(7, "F").Value = "false"

    End If
            
            
Worksheets("Uebersicht").Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Dim MaterialDatenbankZeile As Integer
```

to

```
Dim MaterialDatenbankZeile As Variant
```

otherwise you cannot capture the error value when the `Application.Match`  fails.

FYI pretty much no-one uses `Let` in VBA - you can omit that.